# Formatting top's batch mode output for plotting/graphing

Tags: linux, sorting, awk, sed, cut

I've used top in the following manner to verify how much CPU percentage a certain process is taking up:

```
while true; do printf "`date` : " >> /var/log/besclient_resourcemonitor.txt; top -bn1 | awk '/BESClient/ {print $9}' >> /var/log/besclient_resourcemonitor.txt ; sleep 20; done
```

This results in the following output, truncated:

```
Mon Oct 16 13:37:08 CDT 2017 : 0.0
Mon Oct 16 13:37:29 CDT 2017 : 0.0
Mon Oct 16 13:38:10 CDT 2017 : 1.3
Mon Oct 16 13:38:30 CDT 2017 : 0.0
Mon Oct 16 13:38:51 CDT 2017 : 0.0
Mon Oct 16 13:39:11 CDT 2017 : 1.9
```

I'd like to try and graph this in gnuplot or Excel, but I'm having difficulty getting the data sorted properly to be able to place Date/Time (Columns 1-6) in X and load (at the last column) as Y.  I've tried using cut, sed and awk, but must be missing something.  Since there isn't a common delimiter, I believe this is what's confusing cut.

How would you go about skinning this cat?  BTW, I like cats, so, no cats were harmed in the making of this output.

Comment: `date` accepts a format string. Try `date +%Y-%m-%s_%H:%M:%S`.

Comment: so the final goal is plotting the output? Perhaps, remove `sed` tag and add `gnuplot` instead

Comment: why don't you use a script friendly date format?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how gunplot works, but if you want this data as is (dont want to process further) and just delimiting columns you mentioned is a concern then you can further use awk as follows and you can store output as csv and further import in excel

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=" : "; OFS=","}{print $1, $2}'
```

gives:

```
Mon Oct 16 13:37:08 CDT 2017,0.0
Mon Oct 16 13:37:29 CDT 2017,0.0
Mon Oct 16 13:38:10 CDT 2017,1.3
Mon Oct 16 13:38:30 CDT 2017,0.0
Mon Oct 16 13:38:51 CDT 2017,0.0
Mon Oct 16 13:39:11 CDT 2017,1.9
```

FS and OFS are Field separator and Output field separator